# How to extend life cycle of an activity object

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

I initialize a MediaPlayer object in my main activity to play music. I would like my app to keep playing music when the user closes the app. I guess when the user closes the app, the MediaPlayer object goes out of scope. How can I keep keep the music playing after the app is closed?

Comment: Initialise and hold the MediaPlayer object in a Service - your app should be just a gateway for communicating with the Service, I.e. the Service does most of the work. Loads of example on the net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How extend life cycle of an activity object

You can't.

If you want to run code when your app is in the background, you have to use a `Service`

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at this wrong. Extending the life cycle means opening the door to leaks. There's also a considerable amount of things to keep track of.

The recommended way is via a [Foreground Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground). Your activity ideally binds to your service and controls the music playback via the provided [Binder interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html).

You can also allow the service to be controlled directly through your service's *Ongoing Notification*.

An example of the the above is *Google Play Music*.

Good luck.